# AKS - Cronjob use script file inside PVC

Tags: python, dockerfile, kubectl, kubernetes-pvc, kubernetes-cronjob

I would like to create a cronjob that could get the script file inside PVC and run with it.
Here I have created a PVC inside AKS as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    annotations:
      volume.beta.kubernetes.io/mount-options: dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,uid=999,gid=999
      volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
    name: cronjob-scripts
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany

    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 1Gi
    storageClassName: aks-azure-files
```

After that, I connected it with a pod `general-utils`,
and added a Python script file into there using the below command:
`kubectl -n <NAMESPACE> cp cronjob_script.py general-utils:/var/scripts`

Once confirmed the script files is there in PVC, I create a cronjob as following:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: testing-cronjob
spec:
  schedule: "00 0 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 300
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          imagePullSecrets:
          - name: <SECRET_NAME>
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: cronjob-scripts
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: cronjob-scripts
          containers:
          - name: testing-cronjob
            image: <PYTHON_INSTALLED_ALPINE_IMAGE>
            command: ["py /var/scripts/cronjob_script.py"]
            volumeMounts:
            - name: cronjob-scripts
              mountPath: "/var/scripts"
            imagePullPolicy: Always
```

After created, I manually trigger the cronjob by running:
`kubectl -n <NAMESPACE> create job --from=cronjob/testing-cronjob job-of-testing-cronjob`

However, the pod created by the job throws out below error in the describe events:

```
Warning  Failed     13s (x2 over 13s)  kubelet            
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: 
OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: 
unable to start container process: exec: "py /var/scripts/cronjob_script.py": 
stat py /var/scripts/cronjob_script.py: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Not sure if PVC will be connected after the pod is created, so it becomes a dead loop.

If I want to let cronjob getting script file to run, how should I achieve?

Comment: This post has a number of issues.  It's asking many questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things Kubernetes configuration questions are off topic because they are not about programming https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423039/proposal-for-updated-guidance-for-kubernetes-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation, I found that the error is due to the script file path.
We needs to put the path to `args` instead of `one line` command inside the configuration, i.e.

from

```
- name: testing-cronjob
  image: <PYTHON_INSTALLED_ALPINE_IMAGE>
  command: ["py /var/scripts/cronjob_script.py"]
```

to

```
- name: testing-cronjob
  image: <PYTHON_INSTALLED_ALPINE_IMAGE>
  command: ["py"]
  args: ["/var/scripts/cronjob_script.py"]
```